# How to use Cli-Wallet with a custom node?

Tags: cli-wallet

So I installed Node.js and Cli-Wallet. No when I try to start the wallet, following error occures:

```
user@Device:~$ iota-cli 

/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix it? I can't open the cli-wallet to change the node.

Comment: Are you actually entering an IP and a port or are you just typing "node-IP:port"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an error caused when you install from a package manager. Try running this command and see if you can run the wallet after:

`ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`

After that changing nodes can be done by just typing

`node nodes.iota.fm:80` (or any node you want to use)

**Edit: I see your new issue, you forgot to actually run the IOTA-CLI.**

**I've provided a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BslC7.png) to help you better understand how to run it.**

Comment: Thanks for your help. I devided the question now and answered it. https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1486/cli-wallet-is-not-running-how-to-fix-it/1487#1487