# Cli-Wallet is not running. How to fix it?

Tags: cli-wallet

After perfoming:

> user@Device:~$ iota-cli

I get following Error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/iota-cli-app/lib/config.js:83
  get,
     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/iota-cli-app/index.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the current Version of node.js

Source for my answer:
https://github.com/iotaledger/cli-app/issues/13

Link to [current Version of Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)